# Why is "def", on line 41, getting a syntax error here?

Tags: python, syntax

My code is as follows:

```
import keyboard, clipboard, time
from appscript import app, k
def copyChecker():
    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+1')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy1 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]
        #print(copy1)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+2')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy2 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+3')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy3 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+4')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy4 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+5')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy5 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+6')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy6 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+7')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy7 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+8')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy8 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())]

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+w+9')):
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
        copy9 = clipboard.paste()[: -len(clipboard.paste())

def pasteChecker():
    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+1')):
        clipboard.copy(copy1)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+2')):
        clipboard.copy(copy2)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+3')):
        clipboard.copy(copy3)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+4')):
        clipboard.copy(copy4)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+5')):
        clipboard.copy(copy5)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+6')):
        clipboard.copy(copy6)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+7')):
        clipboard.copy(copy7)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+8')):
        clipboard.copy(copy8)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)

    if (keyboard.is_pressed('control+s+9')):
        clipboard.copy(copy9)
        app('System Events').keystroke('V', using=k.command_down)
def main():
    copyChecker()
    pasteChecker()
while (True):
    main()
```

Thanks a bunch and any help is appreciated.

Comment: On line 39 there is a `[` that is not closed.

Comment: Thanks a ton sorry for making you do that...

Comment: Oh man, why so much code ? Just loop on 1-9 and store copy in a dict. It's always the same thing. :)

Comment: Honestly when I answered I just looked for the bug. Bust as stated by Loïc a loop would be great here. Use the loop iterator in place of the hard coded strings.

Comment: Thanks for that advice and I will do so. Now thinking about it that would make it a lot easier to read, and less time for me to type. Thanks a lot

Comment: Overall less prone to errors and easier to debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 39 needs a close bracket at the end. ]

Comment: Yup, thanks for that... It works now.

Comment: I can't for another 6 minutes...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that all brackets and parenthesis are closed? Seems you missed at least one at the end, just before "def", row 40.

Comment: Yeah I now noticed that, and after fixing that it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: This is more appropriate as a comment, rather than an answer.